# reserving resources in SP 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-calendar, resources

How can I setup reservation calendar for office resources like rooms, devices etc in SP 2013 as shown in the following article for SP 2010

[Enable reservation of resources in a calendar](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Enable-reservation-of-resources-in-a-calendar-0bdb58b9-db48-4c9f-b3f4-b2052f0576bc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After migration to SharePoint 2013 I discovered that these features were excluded from the new platform and saved only as backward compatibility. So, you can migrate your application with installed booking calendar from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013 and you will keep functionality of resource reservation but you cannot activate it on a new SharePoint 2013 application through default interface.

Microsoft officially explained these restrictions by unpopularity of the resource reservation feature: [Features deprecated in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607742%28v=office.15%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#section1)

First, I found a solution for SharePoint 2013 on-premise. It is possible to display the missing site templates including 'Group Work Site'. Then you just need to create a site based on this template and you will get the calendar of resources.

Go to `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\1033\XML`, open **WEBTEMP.XML file**, find an element with **'Group Work Site'** title attribute and change its Hidden attribute from FALSE to TRUE.

Read Complete blog [here](http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/reservation-of-resources-in-sharepoint-2013-and-sharepoint-2013).

Comment: We are on SP 2013 on-premise. Does this mean no reservation calendar for us? Thanks for sharing the article.

Comment: that's mean it is deprecated feature but still available in 2013....but Hidden you have to set hidden false in order to see in 2013.